# Using C++ Copy Constructor for String Concatenation

Tags: c++, string, constructor, copy, concatenation

I wanted to know how to invoke an copy constructor in this concatenation process over here. The s3=s1+s2; should be able to call the copy constructor and assign it to s3. Is it even possible ?
If yes, please help me out here. Thanks

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string.h>

class String
{
    char x[40];

    public:
    String() { }          // Default Constructor

    String( char s[] )
    {
        strcpy(x,s);
    }

    String( String & s )
    {
        strcpy(x,s.x );
    }

    String operator + ( String s2 )
    {
        String res;

        strcpy( res.x,x );
        strcat( res.x,s2.x);

        return(res);
    }

    friend ostream & operator << ( ostream & x,String & s );
};

ostream & operator << ( ostream & x,String & s )
{
    x<<s.x;
    return(x);
}

int main()
{
    clrscr();

    String s1="Vtu";
    String s2="Belgaum";

    String s3 = s1+ s2;      // Should invoke copy constructor to concatenate and assign

    cout<<"\n\ns1 = "<<s1;
    cout<<"\n\ns2 = "<<s2;

    cout<<"\n\ns1 + s2 = "<<s3;

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The way s1=s2 calls an copy constructor, the expression 
String s3 = s1+ s2;
Should also be able to call copy constructor. If you know how, please help out.

Answer (score 0):

First of all define the default constructor like

```
String() { x[0] = '\0'; }
```

As for the copy constructor then it should be declared like

```
String( const String & );
        ^^^^^
```

In this case you can create new objects from temporary objects.

Also I would define this constructor
    String( char s[] )
    {
        strcpy(x,s);
    }

the following way

```
String( const char s[] )
{
    strncpy( x, s, sizeof( x ) );
    x[sizeof( x ) - 1] = '\0';
}
```

This operator also should have the second parameter with qualifier const

```
friend ostream & operator << ( ostream & x, const String & s );
                                            ^^^^^
```

Comment: I know the syntax for it, but everytime its executed the overloaded+ kicks in and executes. Can't i make an call to copy constructor. Is this any good?
 string1(const string1 &s1,const string1 &s2)
        {
            strcpy(name,strcat(s1.name,s2.name));
            
        }

Comment: @user3386500 It is not a copy constructor. It is a constructor with two parameters.

Comment: So how can invoke copy constructor with parameter as s1+s2? Is it possible?

Comment: @user3386500 You can write simply String s( s1 + s2 ); because you already defined the concatenation. It is important that the parameter had qualifier const as I showed in my post.

Comment: Okay thanks, One final question, does that mean i can't use s3=s1+s2; ?
for copy constructor to activate?

Comment: @user3386500 In this statement String s3 = s1 + s2; there is used the copy constructor. In this statement s3 = s1 + s2; there is used the copy assignment operator that you did not define.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class String {
 private:
  string str;

 public:
  String(string str) {
    this->str = str;
  }

  String(const String& other) {
    this->str = other.str;
  }

  String operator+(const String& other) {
    return String(this->str + other.str);
  }

  void operator=(const String& other) {
    this->str = other.str;
  }

  void print() {
    cout << str << endl;
  }
};

int main() {
  String s1("Hello");
  String s2(" World!");
  String s3 = s1 + s2;
  s1.print();
  s2.print();
  s3.print();
  return 0;
}
```